# Chrome Extension Jquery takes a while to load

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, manifest

everyone I am currently building a chrome extension using Jquery. When the page loads and I click my extension button, I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined". But if I wait a two or three seconds, the extension works just fine. I was wondering how I could fix this delay because it breaks the extension whenever I click it too early.

Other extensions I have used don't seem to have this problem.

I have looked at other questions regarding where to place the Jquery file to ensure it loads before my other scripts.

I made sure Jquery is loaded before any other script. What am I doing wrong? Why is there a delay? And how would I go about fixing it?

Manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Test",
  "description": "Test Extension",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "off.png"
  },

 "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery.js", "background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>",
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
  ],

  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "Extension_Design/*",
    "jquery.js"
  ],

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["jquery.js", "content_script.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

background.js

```
//TODO: change to variable associated with tabs
var tabsArray = chrome.tabs.query;
for (var i = 0; i < tabsArray.length; i++) {
  tabsArray[i] = false;
}

// When the icon is clicked:
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  tabsArray[tab.index] = !tabsArray[tab.index];

  if (tabsArray[tab.index]) {
    // Change image to "on.png"
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: "on.png", tabId: tab.id });

    // Run content_script.js with jquery API enabled

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { file: "jquery.js" });    
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { file: "jquery-ui.min.js" });    
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { file: "content_script.js" });
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { code: "console.log('Extension is on')" });
  } else {
    // Change image to "off.png"
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: "off.png", tabId: tab.id });
    // Send a greeting message containing toggle
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { code: "$(document.body).off();" });
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { code: "$(sidebar).detach()" });
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { code: "console.log('Extension is off')" });
  }
});
```

Comment: Does it still happen if you surround your background script with the `ready` function? 
$(document).ready(function() {
    //your background code here
});

Comment: `chrome.tabs.executeScript` is asynchronous as all Chrome API. Inject each next script in the callback parameter.

Comment: @Daniel, By surrounding my background script with the ready function, it is essentially waiting for the document to finish loading. But I'm trying to get my extension to work before the document loads, that is part of the couple seconds of delay.

Comment: @wOxxOm, I will try that method is get back to you. I got it to work by `$(document.body).append('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + chrome.extension.getURL("jquery.js") + '"></script>');` inside the function that appends the extension to the DOM. Is this method better or `chrome.tabs.executeScript` better?

Comment: `executeScript` injects a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) which has certain privileges and runs in an "isolated world", on the other  hand `<script>` element injects the script into the page without any privileges but with access to the page variables. See [the extension architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

Comment: @wOxxOm, Fantastic, it works! and Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lines of chrome.tabs.executeScript* are occurring asynchronously, so sometimes your scripts are executing before jQuery has finished loading. This is causing the undefined reference error. If you inject jQuery before executing your other scripts, then you should not see this error. You can order these chrome.tabs.executeScript* lines as callback functions in your background.js file, as wOxxOm suggested, or inject jQuery & jQuery UI in the content script and then perform the rest of your JS asynchronously. Remember, you can't use the chrome.tabs API in content scripts so the syntax is different to inject JS into the page.

Using callbacks, in background.js:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({ file: "jquery.js" }, function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({ file: "jquery-ui.min.js" }, function(){
       chrome.tabs.executeScript({ file: "content_script.js" });
    });
});
```

Loading script into DOM via script tags, in the content_script.js:

```
function runScripts(){
 var j = document.createElement('script');
 j.type = "text/javascript";
 j.src = chrome.extension.getURL('jquery.js');
 (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]).appendChild(j);

  j.onload = function() {
    console.log('Jquery is loaded.');
    var u = document.createElement('script');
    u.type = "text/javascript";
    u.src = chrome.extension.getURL('jquery-ui.min.js');
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]).appendChild(u);

    u.onload = function() {
     console.log('Both Jquery & Jquery UI are loaded.');
      //Perform jQuery syntax JS stuff asynchronously here...

    };
  };
};
```